# Best Practices for multiple development efforts, different versions of Java

Tags: java, design, engineering

I'm the sole developer working on multiple projects on different versions of Java, plus some Microsoft Sharepoint front end projects. I REALLY need to figure out a better setup for my development environments and would like to know what others use. Please let me know if I should be posting in a different stack* community. Here is what I have to support:

- Java 7 Spring project, developing in STS - I'm working on upgrading
  this to Java 11 and it is going ugly.
- Java 8 Spring Boot Projects,
  developing in STS
- Java 8 Spring Boot app that gets deployed to Azure,
  developing in STS
- Microsoft SharePoint Web Parts in Visual Studio Code, mostly TypeScript/html/css so far

I'm developing in a Windows environment with my JAVA_HOME set to Java 7. It is starting to feel very sloppy and I just feel like there must be a better way to organize this all (multiple projects/different versions of Java). Looking for what other folks are doing.

Comment: [jEnv](https://www.jenv.be/). Not for Windows though I'm afraid...

Comment: [Compliance level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22584427/what-is-compiler-compliance-level-in-eclipse)? Docker? VM? Dual boot? Second dev box? Schizophrenia? Update your resume?

Comment: For instance the **maven** build infrastructure: versioned dependency management, java versions. JAVA_HOME I find obsolete personally. I like Visual Studio, but maybe IntelliJ Community Edition is worth trying.

Comment: @JoopEggen - mentioned JAVA_HOME because I realized Maven is using whatever is specified in JAVA_HOME and I'm not sure if that was messing up things.  Also, I have different versions of the IDE setup so I can run launch one version of STS with Java 11.  As a I said, it's just getting very messy.

Comment: @candied_orange - are you thinking get it all running on Java 11 and then just use STS's compliance level to configure 7/8/11 based on project need?

Comment: @headlikearock if it works you can leave Java home pointing at your latest Java. But do you have the tests that prove to you that it works?